# How to add auto expire session time with Session::put() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am setting some custom session in Laravel.

```
Session::put('key','value')
```

How to set auto expire time with `Session::put()` function in Laravel

Comment: Do you want to remove that `key` from your session after a certain amount of time? Or do you want to remove all your session?

Comment: @iArcadia I want to remove that "key" from session.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot add expire time with `put()`: https://github.com/illuminate/session/blob/master/Store.php#L262

Answer (score 1):

It mays not to be the best solution, but I propose you this.

The first time the user open your site, put a `last_activity` key with the current datetime (or timestamp) as a value.

Then, each time that the user will load a page, before updating your `last_activity` key, check the difference between the current datetime and the last activity (which has the datetime from the previous loaded page, if the session still exists).

You can now remove or not that `key` depending of the result. And finally update your `last_activity` key.

Answer (score -1):

This way you can put value in session in laravel

```
  $data = Session::put('key','value');
```